# Is it possible to download the raw xml file in a Jenkins test job

Tags: xml, jenkins, testing, archive

On a Jenkins job is there a way to download the raw xml file produced by the tests? e.g. Via an extended url, etc?

The nominal way is to archive the xml file.

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test-results.xml'
junit 'test-results.xml'
```

But I figure that Jenkins already has this info in order to create the test failure UI. I'd rather not archive the xml if there's another work around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch the raw XML by doing this -

Say if you want to see for the last completed build

```
<Jenkins URL>/job/<Job Name>/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/api/xml
```

or if you want for a specific build number

```
<Jenkins URL>/job/<Job Name>/<Build number>/testReport/api/xml
```

Comment: Was able to verify this on a Public Jenkins. Namely jenkins.mono-project.com. Had to use a Public Jenkins as my admin has disabled access to this url on our Jenkins :(.

Answer (score 0):

Archive them.

Files in the workspace are not meant to live forever. Archived files are meant to be stored as long as you keep the build logs.

Also if you have a permission model active, you can manage the permissions for the archive separately. And you can then use variables in the URL like `lastSuccessfulBuild` to refer to the last successful build.

And lastly: you can use the [HTML Publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/) as an alternative.